# How to bind to the submit event when HTML5 validation is used?

Tags: jquery, validation, html

Using HTML5 validation...

In HTML5 browsers, validation occurs *before* the `submit` event. So if the form is invalid, the submit event never fires.

I would like to hook an event into the form submit, to fire whether the form validates or not. Here's a small example, where I'm trying to `alert()` when the user submits the form.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title>Example</title></head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="foo" required title="Foo field"/>
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        alert('submit!')
    });
});
```

Interactive demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gCBbR/

My question is: **do browsers provide an alternative event that I can bind to that will run before the validation?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, there is an event for that reason. The event is called [`invalid`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#the-constraint-validation-api) when user tries to submit the for orr when you check validity via HTML5 validation method [`checkValidity()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#dom-cva-checkvalidatity). This event does not fire on `blur` or something like that without calling `checkValidity()` just because you have HTML validation attributes in your `input` tags. But it does fire on before form submit.

From W3C:

> When the `checkValidity(`) method is invoked, if the element is a
>   candidate for constraint validation and does not satisfy its
>   constraints, the user agent must fire a simple event named `invalid`
>   that is cancelable (but in this case has no default action) at the
>   element and return false. Otherwise, it must only return true without
>   doing anything else.

For example you have this markup:

```
<form>
            <input type="text" name="foo" required title="Foo field"/>
            <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Then you need to call `checkValidity()` to fire `invalid` event if the  `input` data is invalid:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input')[0].addEventListener('blur', function(){
        this.checkValidity();
    }, false);

document.querySelectorAll('input')[0].addEventListener('invalid', function(){
        console.log('invalid fired');
    }, false);
```

Look at my example here: http://jsbin.com/eluwir/2

Comment: Actually this not totally true. The invalid event is fired with programmatic constraint validation (checkValidity) *and* interactive form validation (user trys to submit a form with invalid inputs). Additionally there is 2 other big differences, the invalid is fired for each invalid input and submit only once + the invalid event does not bubble to the form (you can use capture...).

Comment: @alexanderfarkas, you are totally right. I misunderstood the specification. Edited my answer. This event fires on before submit here: http://jsbin.com/eluwir/3/edit

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function() {
    $('form').one('submit',function() {
        alert(1);

        [...]

        $(this).submit(); // optional
        return false; // returning false skips validator's trigger
    });
});
```

this code will be executed only once, for permanent handling use `$.bind`

Comment: I think you mis-understood the question. The submit event is never fired if the form fails HTML5 validation.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to use the browser default validation  you should use the following as you need to bind to the default submit then prevent the it and use $.ajax or $.post

```
$("form").bind('submit', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();

        $.post("url",$("form").serialize(),function(data){
                             $("#result").html(data).show();
                              });
       });
```

Comment: Your solution gave me a great idea to separate concerns between onClick (button) and onSubmit (form) . Thanks!