# Fuelux wizard validation input

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fuelux

I have made a form nested inside the fuelux wizard.  The bookstrap required field will not show up if the person clicks the next button.  Is there any methods which can make it a requirement that the user cannot progress by clicking next until the required fields have been entered?

Here is an example of the input

```
  <tr>
  <td>3</td>
    <td><label class="control-label" for="inputCompanyCountry">Country <span style="color:red">*</span></label></td>
    <td><div class="controls controls-extra"><input type="text" id="inputCompanyCountry" name="inputCompanyCountry" value=""required></div></td>
    <td><div class="help-inline">Country of residence</div></td>
  </tr>
```

The scripts used for the next and previous buttons

```
$(function() {
$('#MyWizard').on('change', function(e, data) {
    console.log('change');
    if(data.step===3 && data.direction==='next') {
        // return e.preventDefault();
    }
});

$('#MyWizard').on('changed', function(e, data) {
    console.log('changed');
});
/*$('#MyWizard').on('finished', function(e, data) {
    console.log('finished');
});*/
$('#btnWizardPrev').on('click', function() {
    $('#MyWizard').wizard('previous');
});
$('#btnWizardNext').on('click', function() {
    $('#MyWizard').wizard('next','foo');
});


$('#btnWizardStep').on('click', function() {
    var item = $('#MyWizard').wizard('selectedItem');
    console.log(item.step);
});
});
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to validate without sending the form, you can use jquery.validate. Use the method `$("#form_id").valid();`, it returns true or false depending the status of the form add class "required" to the inputs in question.

```
$('#MyWizard').on('change', function(e, data) {
    console.log('change');
    if(data.step===3 && data.direction==='next') {
        if($("#form_id").valid()){
            // allow change
        }else{
            // cancel change
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: http://bootply.com/72771

This is an example of my problem.  The user should not be able to pass the next button until a value is entered in the input field.

Answer (score 2):

what i did:

```
$('#MyWizard').on('change', function(e, data) {
    var isValid = $('#stepId [required]').valid();
    if (data.direction === 'next' && !isValid) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

If you want to disable moving both ways, then just remove the `data.direction ==='next'` part.

Comment: How did you get the #stepId? struggling with this

Comment: '#stepId' is the 'id' of the step you want to skip.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is wrapping each step in a form, and then on submittal the browser will not proceed until required fields have been filled out. This depends on the browser supporting the 'required' attribute in the form as part of the HTML5 spec, but you might be able to make use of this. There are some links that appear broken in this answer, but there's some starting information as well: [How to bind to the submit event when HTML5 validation is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587511/how-to-bind-to-the-submit-event-when-html5-validation-is-used)

Comment: The problem is the form is divided into several sections so if the user is on chevron #3, they cannot see the required field on chevron #1.  What would be best if they could not click the "next" button until the required fields have been filled out.

Comment: In both this case and the answer above, what you'll need to do is apply a 'disabled' attribute to the buttons. Then you'll to trigger some event when you pass validation, and you'll also need an event handler that listens for that event and removes the disabled attribute. So there's not a single method that will do this, but it isn't that much code to write to do so. Using the example given by Birkto above, you'd put code to remove the disabled attribute where he has ````// allow change````